# get 2 characters from a string

Tags: java, string, substring, talend

I have a string `FILENAME` which actually holds the file names in a foreach loop. The string will be something like:

```
MyFile_TEST_INDIA_20160728
MyFile_TEST_AMERICA_20160728    
MyFile_TEST_GERMANY_20160728
```

I need to get the first 2 characters of the country name. I tried with the below:

```
String rmtdir = Filename.substring(Filename.length() - 12, Filename.length() - 12);
System.out.println(rmtdir);
```

But by using this I could only get the required data for INDIA.
For other countries, I manually need to update the 2nd part of the substring, keeping the extended length of the countries in mind.

Like for America and Germany:

```
String rmtdir = Filename.substring(Filename.length() - 12, Filename.length() - 14);
```

Is there any way to go to the starting index and select number of positions to be selected?

Comment: Is your file name pattern the same? Will it be MyFIle_TEST_United_Kingdom_xxx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the format is like the two examples, I'd use split() and substring()

```
 String test = "MyFile_TEST_INDIA_20160728";
 String countryCode = test.split("_")[2].substring(0,2);
 System.out.println(countryCode); // print IN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a simple yet accurate piece. I am new to java. :)

Comment: You're welcome @Meen, we all used to be new at some point, have fun learning it, it's great! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this part "MyFile_TEST_" will be fixed we can use indexof and substring.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //String str = "MyFile_TEST_INDIA_20160728";
    //String str = "MyFile_TEST_AMERICA_20160728"; 
    String str = "MyFile_TEST_GERMANY_20160728";

    int startIndex = str.indexOf("T_")+2;
    int endIndex = str.indexOf("T_")+4;

    System.out.println(str.substring(startIndex, endIndex));

    }
```

Output - IN, AM and GE

Answer (score 0):

If the format is fixed than you can get it like this

```
 String rmtdir=Filename.substring(12, 14);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex also:- [Demo for regex](https://regex101.com/r/wT7kM8/2)

```
String s = "MyFile_TEST_INDIA_20160728";    
String s2 = s.replaceAll("^\\w+_([a-zA-Z]+)_\\d+$", "$1").substring(0, 2);
```

Out put will be :

```
  IN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to split the string into groups. In your case `MyFile_TEST_INDIA_20160728` could be broken into the groups:

```
(file)_(desc)_(country)_(date)
```

The first three can be matched by the regex `[^_]+`. Meaning a groups of characters that is not an underscore. For date you need 8 digits exactly `\\d{8}`. Altogether this regex is:

```
[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_\\d{6}
// or with groups
([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(\\d{6})
```

Now that you have a regex you can use it parse a string in java by using the `Pattern` and `Matcher` class.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
...

String text = "MyFile_TEST_INDIA_20160728";
String regex = "([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(\\d{8})";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
matcher.find();

System.out.println("file:    " + matcher.group(1));
System.out.println("desc:    " + matcher.group(2));
System.out.println("country: " + matcher.group(3));
System.out.println("date:    " + matcher.group(4));
```

Then getting the first two letters of the country is pretty easy:

```
String country = matcher.group(3).substring(0, 2);
System.out.println("country: " + country);
```